# Failed to convert parameter C# / SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, syntax-error

Getting error:

> Failed to convert parameter value from string to a Int32

I write that code for my form and at finally when run the code and I get an error. I tried to change everything but but any exchange gives me the same error.

[image]

My code:

```
const string sqlText = "INSERT INTO dbo.bd_formular(facultate,domeniul,specializare,forma_invatamant,d_inscriere,nume_prenume,cod,localitate,judet,tara,strada,numar,bloc,scara,etaj,apartament,sector,cod_p,data_nasterii,locul_nasterii,judet_n,tara_n,sex,stare_civila,cetatenie,cetatenie_op,etnie,incadrare,cnp,serie,numar_cnp,eliberat,e_data,studii_preuni,nume_unitate,spec_fili_profil,oras_s,judet_s,tara_s,forma_de_invatamant,medie_bac,durata_studii,data_absolvirii,tipul_diploma,seria_diploma,numarul_diploma,emis_de_catre,data_emiterii,nr_foi_matricole,introducere_date,semnatura) VALUES (@facultate,@domeniul,@specializare,@forma_invatamant,@d_inscriere,@nume_prenume,@cod,@localitate,@judet,@tara,@strada,@numar,@bloc,@scara,@etaj,@apartament,@sector,@cod_p,@data_nasterii,@locul_nasterii,@judet_n,@tara_n,@sex,@stare_civila,@cetatenie,@cetatenie_op,@etnie,@incadrare,@cnp,@serie,@numar_cnp,@eliberat,@e_data,@studii_preuni,@nume_unitate,@spec_fili_profil,@oras_s,@,@judet_s,@tara_s,@forma_de_invatamant,@medie_bac,@durata_studii,@data_absolvirii,@tipul_diploma,@seria_diploma,@numarul_diploma,@emis_de_catre,@data_emiterii,@nr_foi_matricole,@introducere_date,@semnatura)";

using (var con = new SqlConnection(SqlConnectionString))
using (var comm = new SqlCommand(sqlText, con))
{
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@facultate", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = C1.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@domeniul", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = T1.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@specializare", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = T2.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@forma_invatamant", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = C2.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d_inscriere", SqlDbType.Date) { Value = DTP1.Value.ToString() });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@nume_prenume", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = T3.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@cod", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = T4.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@localitate", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = T5.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@judet", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = T6.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tara", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = T7.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@strada", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = T8.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@numar", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = T9.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@bloc", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = T10.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@scara", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = T11.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@etaj", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = T12.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@apartament", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = T13.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@sector", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = T14.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@cod_p", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = T15.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@data_nasterii", SqlDbType.Date) { Value = DTP2.Value.ToString() });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@locul_nasterii", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = T16.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@judet_n", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = T17.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tara_n", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = T18.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@sex", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = C3.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@stare_civila", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = C4.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@cetatenie", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = C5.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@cetatenie_op", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = T19.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@etnie", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = T20.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@incadrare", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = C6.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@cnp", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = T21.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@serie", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = T22.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@numar_cnp", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = T23.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@eliberat", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = T24.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@e_data", SqlDbType.Date) { Value = DTP3.Value.ToString() });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@studii_preuni", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = C7.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@nume_unitate", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = T25.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@spec_fili_profil", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = T26.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@oras_s", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = T27.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@judet_s", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = T28.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tara_s", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = T29.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@forma_de_invatamant", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = C8.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@medie_bac", SqlDbType.Decimal) { Value = T30.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@durata_studii", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = C9.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@data_absolvirii", SqlDbType.Date) { Value = DTP4.Value.ToString() });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tipul_diploma", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = C10.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@serie_diploma", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = T31.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@numar_diploma", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = T32.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@emis_de_catre", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = T33.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@data_emiterii", SqlDbType.Date) { Value = DTP5.Value.ToString() });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@nr_foi_matricole", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = T34.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@introducere_date", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = T35.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@semnatura", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = T36.Text });

    con.Open();
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

SQL Server table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tabela_form] 
(
    [facultate]               VARCHAR (100)  NOT NULL,
    [domeniul]                VARCHAR (100)  NOT NULL,
    [specializare]            VARCHAR (100)  NOT NULL,
    [forma_invatamant]        VARCHAR (100)  NOT NULL,
    [d_inscriere]             DATE           NOT NULL,
    [nume_prenume]            VARCHAR (50)   NOT NULL,
    [cod]                     VARCHAR (10)   NOT NULL,
    [localitate]              VARCHAR (20)   NOT NULL,
    [judet]                   VARCHAR (20)   NOT NULL,
    [tara]                    VARCHAR (20)   NOT NULL,
    [strada]                  VARCHAR (15)   NOT NULL,
    [numar]                   INT            NOT NULL,
    [bloc]                    VARCHAR (5)    NOT NULL,
    [scara]                   VARCHAR (5)    NOT NULL,
    [etaj]                    INT            NOT NULL,
    [apartament]              INT            NOT NULL,
    [sector]                  VARCHAR (1)    NOT NULL,
    [cod_p]                   INT            NOT NULL,
    [data_nasterii]           DATE           NOT NULL,
    [locul_nasterii]          VARBINARY (50) NOT NULL,
    [judet_n]                 VARCHAR (15)   NOT NULL,
    [tara_n]                  VARCHAR (15)   NOT NULL,
    [sex]                     VARCHAR (7)    NOT NULL,
    [stare_civila]            VARCHAR (50)   NOT NULL,
    [cetatenie]               VARCHAR (50)   NOT NULL,
    [cetatenie_op]            VARCHAR(50)            NULL,
    [etnie]                   VARCHAR (50)   NOT NULL,
    [incadrare]               VARCHAR (50)   NULL,
    [cnp]                     INT            NOT NULL,
    [serie]                   VARCHAR (2)    NOT NULL,
    [numar_cnp]               INT            NOT NULL,
    [eliberat]                VARCHAR (10)   NOT NULL,
    [e_data]                  DATE           NOT NULL,
    [studii_preuni]           VARCHAR (20)   NOT NULL,
    [nume_unitate]            VARCHAR (30)   NOT NULL,
    [spec_fili_profil]        VARCHAR (20)   NOT NULL,
    [oras_s]                  VARCHAR (15)   NOT NULL,
    [judet_s]                 VARCHAR (15)   NOT NULL,
    [tara_s]                  VARCHAR (15)   NOT NULL,
    [forma_de_invatamant]     VARCHAR (30)   NOT NULL,
    [medie_bac]               DECIMAL (2, 2) NOT NULL,
    [durata_studii]           INT            NOT NULL,
    [data_absolvirii]         DATE           NOT NULL,
    [tipul_diploma]           VARCHAR (50)   NOT NULL,
    [seria_diploma]           VARCHAR (10)   NOT NULL,
    [numarul_diploma]         INT            NOT NULL,
    [emis_de_catre]           VARCHAR (100)  NOT NULL,
    [data_emiterii]           DATE           NOT NULL,
    [nr_foi_matricole]        INT            NOT NULL,
    [introducere_date]        VARCHAR (30)   NOT NULL,
    [semnatura]               VARCHAR (20)   NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([facultate] ASC)
);
```

Comment: simply like the error said, the string value could not be converted to int

Comment: You can also use comm.Parameters.AddWithValue

Comment: @FabioCampinho: ***NO!*** You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: Thank you @marc_s.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting int parameter with strings like in:

```
comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@cod", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = T4.Text });
```

You should parse the value in all these lines that are integers with something like:

```
comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@cod", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = int.Parse(T4.Text) });
```

Comment: `int.Parse()` would still throw an exception if the value cannot be parsed to int

Comment: @meda, That is true. Thats why i've said something like. If the OP isn't sure that the values can be parsed into int, he should use int.TryParse, or maybe it should throw an exception that the OP should catch to alarm that there is something wrong with the data

Comment: Now. I changed after as you said but he give another error: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: as meda said.... the string cannot be parsed to int. use int.TryParse, to see if the value can be parsed.

Comment: I tryed with int.TryParse and Convert.ToInt32.. and same error

Comment: So, i guess the string doesn't hold a number. debug and see exactly what value it has

Comment: comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@numar", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = int.Parse(T9.Text ) }); he stoped here and give me: 1. when coverting a string  to datetime, parse the string to take before putting each variable into the datetime object... 2. make sure your method arguments are in  the right format.

Comment: This is now an issue with you DateTime field. not the int field. Again you should set the value to datetime not string. remove the tostring from the datetimepicker

Comment: i changed but i have another problem. Conversion failed when converting date from character string. However if you inserts data today,not give error . But if i change and bring other data, then gives me that error.

Answer (score 0):

why you don't use

```
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cod", T4.Text);

comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@facultate", C1.Text);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@domeniul", T1.Text);
    ...
```

**comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d_inscriere", DTP1.Value);**

```
    ...
    etc
```

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: because that :  Input string was not in a correct format